# Job interview question made harder, check all except root?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I was given this problem in an interview, while it seemed really easy at first when I got deeper it neraly sound impossible to me with tons of edge cases.

> requirments:
>
> Imagine a tree where each node can have from 0 to 10 children, each child has its own weight, write a function that does the following:
>
> 1. In case the root has no children return -1;
> 2. else, return the sum of the weights of all children of the tree (except the root itself).

I tried something like:

```
int my_func(node *root) {
    if (root->isleaf())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < root->num_of_children(); ++i)
    {
        result += my_func(root->child[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But this is really bad, for 2 reasons:

1. I am not summing weights of all children.
2. when I reach leaf child, I am summing -1 while I should add 0.

Comment: Write the function that sums the weights of all nodes, root and all; that's just a simple recursion. Then write another function that calls the first one, then subtracts the weight for the root from that total (or alternatively, calls the first on every child and adds up the results). That second function would also handle the special case for root-only tree.

Comment: What does c have to do with that?? I'd probably let you fail the job interview, because of not knowing that there's a difference. Also what's specific in your code regarding to c++11? I don't see any relevance, will remove the tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sure there's a nicer way to tell him that the C tag isn't relevant.

Comment: Based on the literal description, this function should always be returning a negative value.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new function that delegates to your function that handles the case of the root having no children, and removing the weight of the root after calculating the sum. You also forgot to add the weights in your original function. You can fix that by setting `result` to `root->weight` before adding the rest.

```
int sumOfWeightsExceptRoot(node* root) {
  if (!root || root->isLeaf())
    return -1;
  return my_func(root) - root->weight;
}

int my_func(node* root) {
  if (!root)
    return 0;
  int result = root->weight;
  for (int i = 0; i < root->num_of_children(); ++i) {
    result += my_func(root->child[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Iterative version:

```
int sumOfWeightsExceptRoot(node* root) {
  if (!root || root->isLeaf())
    return -1;

  std::stack<node*> s;
  s.push(root);

  int result = -root->weight;
  while (!s.empty()) {
    node* ptr = s.top(); s.pop();
    result += ptr->weight;
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->num_of_children(); i++) {
      s.push(ptr->child[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What if I want them in one single function?

Comment: @mr_calc Then it would need to be a non-recursive function. You would use a `std::stack` and iterate through the nodes doing the same thing. I'll post it.

Comment: @mr_calc Posted.